# Java Immutable Queue

Tags: java, immutability

In the code below I have two linked lists liperm and litemp. I want to initialize litemp first with the values of liperm and then add other values. But it is not working as in it is not initializing them. Can you please help:

```
public class ExamImmutableQueueImpl<E> implements ExamImmutableQueue<E> {

   LinkedList<E> liperm = new LinkedList<E>();
   LinkedList<E> litemp = new LinkedList<E>(liperm);

   public ExamImmutableQueueImpl(LinkedList li){
       System.out.println(li.toString());
   }

   public ExamImmutableQueueImpl(){}

@Override
   public ExamImmutableQueue<E> enqueue(E e) {
       System.out.println(litemp.toString());
       litemp.add(e);

       return new ExamImmutableQueueImpl<>(litemp);
   }

   public final void setQueue(E e){
       liperm.add(e);


   }

   public void getQueue(){
       System.out.println(litemp.toString());
   }





}
```

The main method is:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    ExamImmutableQueueImpl<Integer> o1 = new ExamImmutableQueueImpl<Integer>();
    ExamImmutableQueue<Integer> obj;
    o1.setQueue(2);
    o1.setQueue(1);
    o1.setQueue(2);
    o1.setQueue(3);
    obj = o1.enqueue(6);
```

The Interface is:

```
public interface ExamImmutableQueue<E> {
public ExamImmutableQueue<E> enqueue(E e);}
```

Comment: I can't imagine a use for this except for `[homework]`? When would you use such a collection?

Comment: I created that constructor just for creating the object in the return statement.
For the main class I created an empty constructor

Comment: so you want to have an immutable queue? because this doesn't look like one. `is not working...` can you care to explain HOW it should work??

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Yes I want to create an I mmutable queue, a permanent one (like liperm) and then I I try to add any other element to the queue, it should return a queue with the new element added but the reference should remain to the old queue(liperm). And that is the reason I created a new object each time you try to add an element to the permanent queue and returned it.

Comment: @The Cat I am not getting any error, but litemp is not being initialized with liperm values even if I pass liperm in the constructor when creating litemp. Hope you guys got it.

Comment: first post `ExamImmutableQueue` interface. litemp is not initialized because you always initialize it empty.

Comment: @UmNyobe litemp is being initialized with liperm
   LinkedList<E> litemp = new LinkedList<E>(liperm);

Comment: Even the constructor that takes a LinkedList only prints it it is not assigned to anything (and it is not generic).

Comment: at the point you initialize litemp, liperm is empty. hence what @UmNyobe is saying

Comment: @Yoztastic I have to assign it. But first I am checking if the list passed is correct one or not by printing it. And by correct I mean that that passed list should have the values of liperm as well as litemp

Comment: @Yoztastic initializing later in the code solves the issue. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I will start by giving you an advice : put this code aside and start fresh.
What seems to be wrong here on a design level:

- you didn't quite understand what is a immutable object. Read again. Immutable implies the object state never change after construction.
- You have several public methods where the contract from the interface is only "enqueue".
- You tend to make methods do what they are not expected to do. the constructor who only prints,  `setQueue` which doesnt set any queue. At least choose your names carefully.

Directions :

- `litemp` should not be a class field. Maybe should not exists.
- you need final fields inside your object. Especially the collection `liperm`
- Construct your objects in constructors. The constructor which does nothing may not have its place
- Do you know if the element `E` is assumed to be mutable or immutable? This make a difference on what you can do.
- Focus on implementing `enqueue`. To make things nices, you can also have [Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) as interface.

Note: An immutable queue seems to make no sense to me (given what a queue ***theoretically*** is). Ask again what is the usage of this collection before jumping in implementation.

Answer (score 1):

This is an implement of  ImmutableQueue from Github.
Visit https://github.com/guptaAbhishek/ImmutableQueue

```
package com.liuhao.DataStructures;

import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class ImmutableQueue<E> {
    private static class ImmutableStack<E> {

        private E head; // head is an object of generic type E
        private ImmutableStack<E> tail; // tail is an ImmutableStack object
        private int size; // size of the stack

        /**
         * Default constructor head to null, tail to null, size to 0
         * */
        private ImmutableStack() {
            this.head = null;
            this.tail = null;
            this.size = 0;
        }

        /**
         * Constructor Overloading (E Object, ImmutableStack object tail) head
         * is object tail is tail (ImmutableStack object) size = size of the
         * tail+1
         * */
        private ImmutableStack(E obj, ImmutableStack<E> tail) {
            this.head = obj;
            this.tail = tail;
            this.size = tail.size + 1;
        }

        /**
         * Emptying the stack returning the ImmutableStack
         * */
        public static ImmutableStack emptyStack() {
            return new ImmutableStack();
        }

        /**
         * Checking if stack is empty with their size
         * 
         * @return true of false if Stack is empty or not
         * */
        public boolean isEmpty() {
            return this.size == 0;
        }

        /**
         * Push into the stack
         * 
         * @param E
         *            object
         * @return ImmutableStack with object
         * */
        public ImmutableStack<E> push(E obj) {
            return new ImmutableStack<E>(obj, this);
        }

        /**
         * Take stack object and push the head of the tail stack to the stack do
         * this until the stack is empty
         * 
         * @return reverse stack
         * */
        public ImmutableStack<E> toReverseStack() {
            ImmutableStack<E> stack = new ImmutableStack<E>();
            ImmutableStack<E> tail = this;
            while (!tail.isEmpty()) {
                stack = stack.push(tail.head);
                tail = tail.tail;
            }
            return stack;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Two stack for enqueue and dequeue the element from the queue order for
     * enqueue reverse for dequeue
     * 
     * */
    private ImmutableStack<E> order;
    private ImmutableStack<E> reverse;

    /**
     * Default constructor ImmutableQueue two empty stacks
     * 
     * */
    public ImmutableQueue() {
        this.order = ImmutableStack.emptyStack();
        this.reverse = ImmutableStack.emptyStack();
    }

    /**
     * Constructor overloading Using two immutable stack order and reverse
     * 
     * */
    public ImmutableQueue(ImmutableStack<E> order, ImmutableStack<E> reverse) {
        this.order = order;
        this.reverse = reverse;
    }

    /**
     * Balancing the Queue reverse the order stack and assign it to reverse
     * stack and make order stack empty
     * */
    private void balanceQueue() {
        this.reverse = this.order.toReverseStack();
        this.order = ImmutableStack.emptyStack();
    }

    /**
     * Enqueue Object if object is null throw IllegalArgumentException
     * 
     * @return ImmutableQueue with object
     * */
    public ImmutableQueue<E> enqueue(E object) {
        if (object == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        return new ImmutableQueue<E>(this.order.push(object), this.reverse);
    }

    /**
     * Dequeue from the queue if Queue is empty then throw
     * NoSuchElementException
     * 
     * if Reverse Stack is not empty then return Immutable queue with reverse
     * stack's tail object
     * 
     * else reverse the Order ImmutableStack and take the tail of this and clean
     * the order ImmutableStack
     * 
     * @return ImmutableQueue
     * */
    public ImmutableQueue<E> dequeue() {
        if (this.isEmpty())
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        if (!this.reverse.isEmpty()) {
            return new ImmutableQueue<E>(this.order, this.reverse.tail);
        } else {
            return new ImmutableQueue<E>(ImmutableStack.emptyStack(), this.order.toReverseStack().tail);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Getting the peek of the queue if Object is empty throw and Exception
     * NoSuchElementException. if reverse stack is Empty balanceQueue.
     * 
     * @return head of the reverse stack
     * */
    public E peek() {
        if (this.isEmpty())
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        if (this.reverse.isEmpty())
            balanceQueue();
        return this.reverse.head;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size() == 0;
    }

    public int size() {
        return this.order.size + this.reverse.size;
    }

    public double percentage(double x) {
        double value = 0;
        if (!this.isEmpty()) {
            value = size() * x / 100;
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution has been taken from GitHub and complete solution with Time Complexity Proof can be seen on
[GitHub](https://github.com/vivekFuneesh/Constant-Queue) and created by Vivek Mangla.

Immutable Queue Algorithm can be better understood in terms of Linked List , very right approach.

A singly Linked List can be made to act like an immutable queue such that whenever an enqueue is performed only new object with front and rear is to be modified whereas previous object will still be representing previous queue.And hence unnecessary copy is not made.

It can also be stated that if previous object is enqueued more than once than we have no other option left but to copy that whole queue and create a new object with front and rear pointing to front(First) element and rear pointing to last one.

The complete code using linked list can be seen as::

```
 * This has been released under GPL v3 Licence by Vivek Mangla 2014.
 * For More Information go to::     http://www.gnu.org/licenses/ 
 * AlgoRithM::::::
 * 
 * According to the Immutable Queue Concept******
 * 
 * If suppose there is an object q representing an Immutable Queue
 *             Now if we perform an enQueue() operation then,
 *                             this object will STILL Represent The Previous Queue
 *                             and a new Object q1 of Immutable Queue will be representing 
 *                                 new Queue with 1 extra element then previous one.
 *                      *************similar argument for dequeue()operation *************
 * 
 *     *******It MEANS THAT THERE IS NO BOUNDATION ON MEMORY FOR an OBJECT..
 * 
 *                i.e.  it is NOT NECESSARY that  a new Object MUST HAVE A 
 *                        WHOLE NEW MEMORY SPACE Of New Queue it is representing.********
 * 
 *BUT If we are EnQueing a value in previous persistent Object MORE_THAN_ONCE than we have  to allocate a Whole new Memory Space
 * 
 * 
 * Using the Above CONCEPT ...
 * 
 * I have created an algorithm to make a Linked List to work like an Immutablequeue.
 * 
 * In this Algorithm,
 *       A new Object may be using  Same Memory Space as Previous One's 
 *         but with certain RESTRICTIONS so that....<<<<.....It is NOT going to CONTRADICT ABOVE CONCEPTS...>>>>>
 *       And Those <Restrictions> are::
 *                                     <1>..<Current Queue Object's front and rear are not to be modified >
 *                                     <2>..<Current Queue Object's SIZE is not to be Modified>
 *       And Hence <Modifications> will be done only on::
 *                                      <1>..<Previous Linked List node's next value ..(If necessary)>
 *                                      <2>..<new Linked List node's data value>
 *                                      <3>..<new Queue Object's rear,front and SIZE value>
 *                                      <4>..<In worst case copy whole Queue of Current Object for  new Object >
 * 
 * <<WHERE rear is a reference to last element of Linked_List and front is First element of Linked_List>>
 * 
 * <<...NOTE::!!!!THE CURRENT QUEUE OBJECT'S Variable Values Are Not Modified At ALL...!!!!>>
 * 
 **************************<********************************************************************************>************* 
 */








import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class IQ1<E>{


    /*************************<***********************************************************************>***********************
     * The Object of this class is having 3 Variables...
     * 
     * 1.> front  :: for keeping track of head of this Object..
     * 2.> rear   :: for keeping track of end of this Object..
     * 3.> SIZE   :: for keeping track of number of elements of this Object..
     *********************<*******************************************************************************>******************* 
     */


    List front=null,rear=null;
    int SIZE=0;
    IQ1<E> IQ1=null;
    static List list=null,node=null,p=null,p1=null;

    public IQ1(){}

    /************************************
     ********************************************************************
     * enqueue(E e) operation 
     ********************************************************************
     * 
     * if(parameter passed is null){
     *                               THROW ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_EXCEPTION ;
     *                             }
     * 
     * else if(it is not null){
     * 
     *                         Create a new List Node.. List list=new List();
     *                         Now data part of this list contains value passed in parameter ;
     *                         Create a new Immutable Queue Object..IQ1<E> IQ1=new IQ1<E> ;
     *                         Now ,
     *                           if((current Object's front is null)OR
     *                                 (it's front is just one step ahead of it's rear i.e.
     *       <this object has been created by removing last element from another object whose rear  was in somewhere middle of list>)){
     *                                           new Object's front is equal to new List Node formed ;
     *                                           new Object's rear is equal to new List Node Formed ;
     *                                                             }
     * 
     *                           else if(this object's rear is  referring to last element){
     *                                     new Object's front is equal to current Object's front ;
     *                                     new Object's rear is equal to new List Node Formed ;
     *                                }
     *                           else{
     *                            << Create a Duplicate Queue of Current Object and adjust new Object's rear and front references>>
     *                           }
     *                           
     *                           new Object's SIZE is 1 More than current Object's SIZE ;
     *                          
     *                          }
     * 
     * return null;
     *****************************************<******************************************>************************************                      
     */


    /************************<****************************************************************>************
     * <<TIME_COMPLEXITY>>
     *              <1.>..<Best Case::>  O(1)
     *              <2.>..<Worst Case::> Less Than |_O(n/2)_|<< WHERE, n IS no. of elements enqueued>> 
     * <<****FOR CALCULATION OF TIME COMPLEXITY SEE END OF THIS PROGRAMM****>>
     ***************************<***********************************************************>****************
     */



    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
     public IQ1<E> enqueue(E e){

        if(e==null)throw new IllegalArgumentException();/** <<YOU_MAY_HANDLE_THIS_EXCEPTION_ON_YOUR_OWN>> **/

            list=new List();
            list.object=e;
            IQ1=new IQ1<E>();
            if((front==null)||(rear.next==front)){IQ1.rear=IQ1.front=list;}
            else if (rear.next==null){
                IQ1.front=front;
                IQ1.rear=list;
                rear.next=list;
            }
            else{
                p=front;p1=null;
                node=new List();
                node.object=p.object;IQ1.front=node;
                p1=node;p=p.next;
                while(p!=rear.next){
                    List node1=new List();
                    node1.object=p.object;
                    p1.next=node;p1=node;p=p.next;
                }
                p1.next=list;
                IQ1.rear=list;
            }

            IQ1.SIZE=SIZE+1;

            return IQ1;

     }


    /**************************<*************************************************************************************>********
     * *********************************
     * dequeue() Operation
     * *********************************
     * 
     * Now Dequeue operation is little bit TRICKY..
     * Because We have to remove first element BUT CURRENT OBJECT's Bounds MUST NOT BE CHANGED
     * SO,
     * 
     * if(current's front is null i.e. EMPTY OR..... if it's rear.next is  referring to it's front i.e. 
     *                                 previous object was containing single item and then a dequeue operation was performed
     *                                 on it and allocated to current object){
     *                                                                         THROW EXCEPTION ;
     *                                                                       }
     * 
     *                                       Create a new Immutable Queue Object;
     *                                       it's front will refer to current's front.next;
     *                                       it's rear will refer to current's rear;
     *                                       it's SIZE will be 1 LESS than current's SIZE;
     *                                       return this new Object;
     * 
     * *****************************<******************************************************************************>***********
     */

    /***********************<*************************************************************************************>
     * <<Time_Complexity>>..
     *                   <O(1)...in ALL CASES>
     ************************<************************************************************************************>*
     */


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
     public IQ1<E> dequeue(){

        if((front==null)||(rear.next==front)){
            rear=null;front=null;
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
            /** <<YOU_MAY_HANDLE_THIS_EXCEPTION_ON_YOUR_OWN>> **/
        }

        IQ1=new IQ1<E>();
        IQ1.front=front.next;
        IQ1.rear=rear;
        IQ1.SIZE=SIZE-1;

         return IQ1;

     }


    /******************************<********************************************************************************>**********
     ***********************
     * peek() Operation
     ***********************
     * 
     * if(current's front is null i.e. EMPTY OR..... if it's rear is  refering to it's front i.e. 
     *                                 previous object was containing single item and then a dequeue operation was performed
     *                                 on it and allocated to current object){
     *                                                                         THROW EXCEPTION ;
     *                                                                       }
     * 
     *                                       return current Object's front.object ;
     * 
     *****************************<**********************************************************************************>********
     */

     /**
     * <<Time_Complexity>>..
     *                   <O(1)...in ALL CASES>
     ****************************<*************************************************************************************>
     */


     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
     public E peek(){
         if((front==null)||(rear.next==front))throw new NoSuchElementException();/** <<YOU_MAY_HANDLE_THIS_EXCEPTION_ON_YOUR_OWN>> **/

         return (E)front.object;


     }


     /**************************<**********************************************************************************>***********
      *<************************
      * size() Operation
      *************************>
      *                                                 return SIZE ;
      * 
      *************************<**********************************************************************************>************ 
      * 
      */

    /*******************************************<****************************************>*************************************
     *
     * <<Time_Complexity>>..
     *                   <O(1)...in ALL CASES>
     *******************************************<******************************************>***********************************
     */

     public int size(){

             return SIZE;


    }


}

/*****************************<**************************************************************************************>****
 ****************************************************
 * Linked List Has Been Used To Store Pushed Element.
 * class List is used to declare Linked list  Node.
 * This class is also a Generic Class to support Generic data Types.
 ****************************************************
 * 
 * It has 2 variables::
 *     1.> A Generic Reference variable   E object;
 *     2.> A  next reference which refers to next node  List next=null;
 ****************************<**************************************************************************************>***** 
 */


class List<E>{


    E object;/**<<Node Data Part Can Contain Any Object>>**/
    List next=null;/***<<Reference to next Node>>**/
}
```

Hope this will help.